# Make a sealed class the Observer of its own Observable<T> property

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, observer-pattern

I have a sealed class. It has a property
'

```
private IObservable<AnotherClass> observable
```

'.

1. I want to make this class as an observer and monitor the change in the above property.
2. I want to call onNext() whenever there is a change in this property.
3. I want to call a custom method1() in .onNext(). like onNext( call Method1(pass the observable data)).
   Since this is a sealed class, I cannot use Virtual onNext() as I found in many examples.

How do I achieve these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `IObserver<AnotherClass>` and subscribe to the observable?

```
public sealed class AnObserver : IObserver<AnotherClass>
{
    private readonly IObservable<AnotherClass> observable;

    public AnObserver()
    {
        observable = ...;
        observable.Subscribe(this);
    }

    void IObserver<AnotherClass>.OnCompleted() { }

    void IObserver<AnotherClass>.OnError(Exception error) { }

    void IObserver<AnotherClass>.OnNext(AnotherClass value)
    {
        Method1(value);
    }

    public void Method1(AnotherClass value)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid implementing `IObserver<AnotherClass>` - it usually goes wrong. By doing so, in this case, you have exposed the inner workings of the class to the outside world.

Comment: You also have a dangling `IDisposable` in code your code when you call `Subscribe`. That should force the class to implement `IDisposable` to do a clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would tackle this situation.

```
public sealed class ThisClass : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IObservable<AnotherClass> observable;
    private readonly IDisposable subscription;

    public ThisClass()
    {
        observable = ...;
        subscription = observable.Subscribe(x => Method1(x));
    }

    private void Method1(AnotherClass value)
    {
       ...
    }

    private bool disposedValue = false;

    void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                subscription.Dispose();
            }
            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
}
```

This doesn't expose anything unnecessary to the outside world and it cleans up on dispose.